Issues compiling older ASP.NET Webforms app in .NET 4.8.1 in Visual Studio 2022
I originally had an old site building in Visual Studio 2019, but since getting a new laptop and going to Visual Studio 2022, it won't build any longer and I get the below errors shown in the screenshot.
It was originally written in .NET 3.5 using ASP.NET Webforms. Then I switched to .NET 4.8.1 and it ran in Visual Studio 2019. Now it won't run or build in VS 2022. It only errors on one of the projects it seems - a project library.


when you installed VS 2022 did you check the optional .NET 4.8.1 option?

Is there any update? Have you installed the needed components in VS Installer?

First, make sure all of the workflows are installed for webforms development. (the project templates are not installed by default).
Hence, these:

Next up?
Make sure you have a reference to Microsoft.CSharp.
If not, then right click on references, and add it:

